# New DisplayPort monitor does not work when its plugged in alone. Works when an HDMI monitor is also plugged in

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

So I got a new Display port monitor for my Dual-Boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 system. I thought I broke my Ubuntu partition when I booted because I was messing with my partitions (Separate reason) because my new monitor was not receiving a signal. I accidentally hit my keyboard and heard the ubuntu log in screen.

Upon investigation I realized that the DisplayPort monitor will not work on its own. If it is plugged in alone it will not get a signal. As soon as I plug in an HDMI monitor at the same time, it will mirror the HDMI monitor but the second I unplug the HDMI monitor, the DisplayPort turns off again. If I attempt to extend the display to both monitors, the HDMI will work and it acts like the DisplayPort is working but it simply goes blank.

I am extremely confused.

Comment: Is this issue present in Windows as well?

Comment: No, I ended up uninstalling Ubuntu completely and trying to reinstall. The same thing happens with the Ubuntu Boot Media that I created. Only the HDMI works, when theyre both plugged in, the HDMI becomes the second screen for extending but the DC is still blank. Does not happen on Windows.